# Solution within 8 significant figures of the exact solution

Tags: python, significant-digits

I am writing a program in python and I want my solutions to return within 8 significant figures of the exact solution.

I have searched the forums here, however there doe not seem to be any direct answer.  I want a simple solution to make sure that the answer the program is computing is within that limit.  I know it should only take 2, maybe three lines of code, I'm just not sure how to make it happen.

For example:

```
    TOL = 1.0000001 to 0.99999999
```

The solution should be in this range.

Comment: ``abs(obtained_value - expected_value) / abs(expected_value) < 1e-8``?

Comment: Please clarify. Do you know the solution beforehand (why do you need the program then)? If not, then what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Unless you already know the right result, this is not something you can solve with a few lines of boilerplate code. You have to do actual numerical analysis to establish error bounds.

Answer (score 1):

```
epsilon = 0.00000001
if abs(solution_expected - solution) <= epsilon:
    print "OK"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while x < 0.99999999 or x > 1.0000001:
    # stuff
```